# how to manage obsolete branches on github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I usually develop new features of my codes in dedicated branches, then merge them to master.

The problem with this is that after some time I have a lot of obsolete branches that are cluttering the github interface, where there might be instead branches which are actively developed.

Is there a way to archive them somehow, or should I just delete them, as the commits have already been merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already merged branches and have no need to develop on them anymore, then it's safe to delete them. You don't loose any commit, as they have been merged and are now stored in master.

I would only propose to leave branches you actively develop

Comment: And since the merge commit's message normally includes the branch name, not even that is lost.